# Javascript associative array not working on Jquery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a associative array `parentTds` however it's not working the way I would like.

```
var parentTds = {};
var index = 0;
$.each(clone, function () {
    var $currentItem = $(selectedActivities[index]);
    var $currentItemTd = $currentItem.closest('td');
    console.log($currentItemTd.get(0));
    var borderLeft = 0;
    console.log(parentTds[$currentItemTd.get(0)]);
    console.log(parentTds[$currentItemTd]);
    if (typeof parentTds[$currentItemTd.get(0)] === "undefined") {
        console.log('NOT OK');
        borderLeft++;
        parentTds[$currentItemTd.get(0)] = $currentItemTd;
    } else {
        console.log('OK');
    }
    index++;
});
```

For some reason `parentTds[$currentItemTd.get(0)]` always returns the 1st item stored. I get `NOT OK` just the 1st time the loop runs whereas I should be getting `NOT OK` a few more times. I suspect the problem is `parentTds[$currentItemTd.get(0)]` itself.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Hint: JavaScript *object* (not "associative array") property names (keys) are always strings. `$currentItemTd.get(0)` is not a string, but when you try to use it as a key it gets coerced to a string.

Comment: Could you please provide some explanation of what 'clone' and 'selectedActivities' contain. Also what is the purpose of this function, are you trying to get the parent 'td' elements to an object in the DOM. An object can only have one parent, so the list should only contain one item. Unless you are tring to get all 'td' in a row of a table? This question requires a little bit more clarification on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @nnnnnn: You are correct. I ended up using Arrays `[]` instead of associate arrays and works exactly like it should now.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not as forgiving as for example PHP. When you use this:

```
if (typeof parentTds[$currentItemTd.get(0)] === "undefined") {
```

`$currentItemTd.get(0)` might be evaulated as 0 and therefore the reference is always `parentTds[0]`

In these circumstance I use to break up the code-block and do something like this:

```
var cig = $currentItemTd.get(0);
if (typeof parentTds[cig] === "undefined") {
```